# How to build & connect OpenCart site's from my android app?

Tags: android, opencart

I mean, I just want some guidance or at least some idea to start with.
I have installed  open cart site. Now I want to develop an Android app that will show my products & enables to take order & update database of opencart site.

*Basically is this possible?*

If yes then how can I connect & read/write opencart site's database from my android app? Any suggestions?

I request you, please provide me detail information.
Thanks in advance

Comment: There are two ways: you want to make an android app from scratch and used RESTApi or open in Webview in android. What you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing that is by creating a web app ( the sole purpose of the app would be just to redirect to the website) .
this might help you this is some documentation on the developer.android.com:
[click here](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html)

so your activity_main.xml should look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

and your oncreate() in mainActivity class would look like this :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
     webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);

    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

this should do the trick . But again this would not be a native app but just an app to redirect to the website . 
Drawbacks:

1) might take time to load the data from the server .

2) if you click back button after choosing some option on the app the app will rollback by closing it . As in, it won't go back to the previous window as the whole control is with the website and not with the app and the back buttons are binded to the app and not the website .

3) If you try to log in with facebook or google for you app the one button click login won't be enabled as the app won't have any cache memory to save you credentials . Every time to log in you would have to type in the username and password .

(someone correct me if i am wrong or if there is a way to handle it )

Even i am looking for a better way to create an app for my opencart website if i find something i will update it here .
 But this way might be the easiest way to solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks...if i wish to create a android application from scratch ..& with the use of REST API i will try to connect to web site ,can you tell me how to call the REST API from android application.